# How to access cookies inside a Cypress request to a different domain?

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, cypress, x-xsrf-token

I'm trying to authenticate at a different domain as part of a Cypress test using `cy.request`. The authentication request needs to contain the value of the XSRF-TOKEN cookie as a header. This is easily solved when on the same baseURL as the authentication domain: visit the domain, read the cookie via `cy.getCookie`, then make the request. Since cypress does not allow visiting multiple domains in a single test a different workflow is needed.

My solution right now is to replace the initial `cy.visit` with a `cy.reqeuest` (this sets the cookie as verified by looking at the request headers of the second request). However, I can't figure out how to read this cookie before I make the second authentication request. `cy.getCookies()` is empty, and `document.cookie` is empty. The response of the `cy.request` only contains a "set-cookie" header the first time, and I can't figure out how to read the default headers of the `cy.request` since `cy.intercept` does not work with `cy.request`.

Sketch of my attempt (where `c.value` is `null`):

```js
cy.request({url: "https://notbaseurl/login"}).then(res => {
  cy.getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN").then(c => {
    cy.request({url: "https://notbaseurl/auth", method: "POST", headers: {"X-XSRF-TOKEN": c.value}})
  })
})
```

Comment: I think that `cy.getCookie` only gets the cookie from the domain that you call `cy.visit` on. However, [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3221#issuecomment-498274788) workaround might sort of help you out. Alternatively, you could parse the response headers for the cookie if `cy.getCookie` doesn't work out

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8956

Comment: Did the work around in the github issue worked for you? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8956#issuecomment-1028288886